# Java multithreading: Plane and runway case study example

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

So hey everyone, i'm actually new with coding and had a lot of problems with it even with the basic.

So my lecturer give this case study: simulate number of plane and 4 runway that can accommodate 1 plane to landing at a time. If all 4 runway is occupied, other planes have to wait for one or more of them to take off. Its hard for me so i try with 2 runways and 4 planes first.

The Plane is thread class and Runway is normal class. What i've done so far:

1. Main Class

   ```
      public class Main {
           public static void main(String[] args) {
               Runway r[] = new Runway[2];
               for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                   r[i] = new Runway(i);
               }

               Plane p[] = new Plane[4];

               for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++){
                   p[i] = new Plane(i, r[0], r[1]);
                   p[i].start();
               }
           }
       }
   ```
2. Runway Class

   ```
       public class Runway {
           private int id;
           private Lock l;
           public boolean available = true;

           public Runway(int id){
               this.id = id;
               l = new ReentrantLock();
           }

           public boolean landing(int idp){
               boolean i;
               i = l.tryLock();
               if (i == true) {
                   available = false;
                   System.out.println("Plane " + idp + " is landing on Runway: " + id);
               }
               return i;
           }

           public void takeOff(int idp){
               System.out.println("Plane " + idp + " is take off from Runway: " + id);
               available = true;
               l.unlock();
           }
       }
   ```
3. Plane Class

   ```
       public class Plane extends Thread {
           private Runway r1, r2;
           private int id, tag;
           private boolean i = false;

           public Plane(int id, Runway r1, Runway r2){
               this.id = id;
               this.r1 = r1;
               this.r2 = r2;
           }

           public void run(){
               if (i == false) {
                   if (r1.available == true) {
                       i = r1.landing(id);
                       tag = 1;
                   } else if (r2.available == true) {
                       i = r2.landing(id);
                       tag = 2;
                   }
               }

               sleep();

               if (tag == 1 & i == true){
                   r1.takeOff(id);
                   i = false;
               } else if (tag == 2 & i == true) {
                   r2.takeOff(id);
                   i = false;
               }
           }

           private void sleep(){
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(8)*100);
               }catch (Exception e){}
           }
       }
   ```

This is the result...

```
Plane 1 is landing on Runway: 0
Plane 3 is landing on Runway: 1
Plane 1 is take off from Runway: 0
Plane 3 is take off from Runway: 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Not all planes are landed, i know this is basic but any help is appreciated :D

Comment: are you allowed to use `synchronised` statements?

Comment: yeah i can use any method bro @gapvision

Comment: Your code consists of only one attempt, so it will do only one attempt, doing nothing if that attempt failed. So the minimum to do is to add a *loop* until the attempt succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach which is an alternative to synchronizing access the shared state . Marking a variable as volatile is a 'lite' alternative to synchronization that has less runtime overhead . It tells the JVM memory manager to guarantee the 'liveness' of the variable to all accessing threads

EDIT

- I've made some modifications after i realised that the volatile keyword did not guarantee atomicity around the operation of attempting to land a plane.
- I also realised that the ids are never modified after construction and so require no volatile keyword

import java.util.*;
    import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

```
public class Airport {

    /**
     * if number of planes is less than or equal to twice the number of runways
     * the execution will terminate ie all planes that want to land
     * will land and all those that wish to take off will take off .
     * Otherwise there wont be enough runways for the landing planes and the execution will
     * go on indefinitely .
     */
    static Runway r[] = new Runway[10];
    static Plane p[] = new Plane[20];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //instantiate array of planes
        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++){
            p[i] = new Plane(i);
        }

        //instantiate runways and allocate planes to runways
        List<Plane> planes = Arrays.asList(p);
        Iterator<Plane> iterator;
        Collections.shuffle(planes);
        iterator= planes.iterator();
        for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
            Plane p;
            try {
                p= iterator.next();
            }catch ( RuntimeException e){
                p= null;
            }
            r[i] = new Runway(i,p);
        }

        //display initial state
        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++){
            Runway runway=getUsedRunway(p[i]);
            System.out.println("plane "+p[i].id + " is "+(runway==null?"waiting to land":("on runway "+runway.id)));
        }

        System.out.println("======== Begin! ============");

        //let the games begin
        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++){
            p[i].start();
        }
    }


    private static class Runway {
        //only ever read after construction . no need for special handling for concurreny
        private int id;

        /**
         * volatile keyword gives atomic read and atomic write operation in isolation .
         * However to land the plane we need to set the runway's plane reference value based on its current value .
         * This scenario is called out specifically by B Goetz in this article https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/
         * ( and in his book Javas one in which volatile is insufficient for thread safety
         * We need an atomic compare and set
         */
        private AtomicReference<Plane> planeAtomicReference;

        public Runway(int i, Plane p) {
            id =i;
            planeAtomicReference = new AtomicReference<>();
            planeAtomicReference.set(p);
        }
    }


    private static class Plane extends Thread {
        //only ever read after construction . no need for special handling for concurreny
        private int id;

        Plane(int i){
            id=i;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Runway runway=getUsedRunway(this);
            if(runway==null){
                System.out.println("plane "+id+" wants to land");
                Runway availableRunway = getAvailableRunway();
                while ((availableRunway=atomicallyAttempToLandPlane(this))==null) {
                    System.out.println("no runway available yet for plane " + id);
                    try {
                        sleep(30);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("landed plane "+id+" on runway "+availableRunway.id);
            }else {
                System.out.println("plane "+id+" wants to take off from runway "+runway.id);
                runway.planeAtomicReference.set(null);
                System.out.println("plane "+id+" has taken off from runway ");
            }
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param plane
         * @return
         */
        private Runway atomicallyAttempToLandPlane(Plane plane) {
            for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                if(r[i].planeAtomicReference.compareAndSet(null,plane)){
                    return r[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     *  does not require synchronization since the size of the arrays is fixed during execution and the elements
     *  to which they refer is also fixed .  only the internal state of elements themselves is open to change
     *  and that has been guaranteed  by marking it as volatile as well as additional atomic behaviour
     * @return
     */
    private static Runway getAvailableRunway(){
        for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
            if(r[i].planeAtomicReference.get() ==null){
                return r[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }



    /**
     *  does not require synchronization since the size of the arrays is fixed during execution and the elements
     *  to which they refer is also fixed .  only the internal state of elements themselves is open to change
     *  and that has been guaranteed  by marking it as volatile as well as additional atomic behaviour
     * @param plane
     * @return
     */
    private static Runway getUsedRunway(Plane plane){
        for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
            final Plane planeOnRunway  = r[i].planeAtomicReference.get();
            if(planeOnRunway !=null && planeOnRunway.id==plane.id){
                return r[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach this problem by considering the planes as threads, and number of runways as the number of locks in the semaphore.

Then the code will go something like this:

```
public class Runway {

  Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(4);

  public void landThePlane() {

    try {
        semaphore.acquire();
        // code to land the plane
        System.out.println("The plane is landing");
        Thread.sleep(3000); // just to show you in the console that the next 4 
                            // threads will be executed afterwards - not imp 
        semaphore.release();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Runway runway = new Runway();
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        executorService.execute(() -> runway.landThePlane());
    }
}
```

}